# Reiterate over dataframe with specific changing variable

Tags: python, pandas

I have a number of dataframes that look similar to the following:

```
df1:
country  value
A        8.518074e+11
B        1.138434e+11
C        8.745698e+10
D        7.543453e+10
E        6.387533e+10

df2:
country  value
A        3.897267e+10
B        3.589588e+10
C        3.077954e+10
D        2.868014e+10
E        2.690948e+10
```

and so on. df1, df2 etc. are different categories that contain the same set of (country) variables with different values. The goal is to take all the dataframes and get the category with the maximum value for each country. In the example above it would be e.g.:

```
A, 8.518074e+11
```

for country A and so on. I know how to get this value by hand:

```
maxA = max(("df1", df1["A"]), ("df2", df2["A"]))

maxA
("df1", 8.518074e+11)
```

But if I do it like this, I need to exchange the "A" in the example by "B", "C" for all the variables. How can I do this automatically? I would need to replace the variable in question by some kind of placeholder like this:

```
maxX = max(("df1", df1["X"]), ("df2", df2["X"]))
```

and then reiterate over the dataframes to get the results for every country. However, this is different from reiterating over a simple list, because only a specific variable should change. Is there a handy solution for this instead of doing it by hand?

many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, set `country` to be the index for every dataframe.

```
df_list = [df1, df2, ...]
for i, df in enumerate(df_list):
     df_list[i] = df.set_index('country')
```

Next, concatenate them by axis, find the `max` along each row, and reset the index.

```
df = pd.concat(df_list, axis=1)\
       .max(axis=1)\
       .to_frame('max_value')\
       .reset_index()

df

  country     max_value
0       A  8.518074e+11
1       B  1.138434e+11
2       C  8.745698e+10
3       D  7.543453e+10
4       E  6.387533e+10
```

---

If you want an indicator in your result, you'll need to modify your code a bit, to add a new `indicator` column, and then perform a `concat`enation along the 0<sup>th</sup> axis, and find the `idxmax` of each group -

```
df_list = [df1, df2, ...]
for i, df in enumerate(df_list):
     df_list[i] = df.assign(indicator=i + 1)
```

```
df = pd.concat(df_list, ignore_index=True)
df.loc[df.groupby('country')['value'].idxmax().values]

df

  country         value  indicator
0       A  8.518074e+11          1
1       B  1.138434e+11          1
2       C  8.745698e+10          1
3       D  7.543453e+10          1
4       E  6.387533e+10          1
```

Comment: thanks, but when I try to apply this, I get the following error:

`'Series' object has no attribute 'set_index'`. 

the error points to the third row (the set_index function)

Comment: @palacinak Okay. In your question, you say `I have a number of dataframes`, and now you claim they are series. What am I supposed to believe they are?

Comment: @COLDSPEED hm it doesnt work, but gives me some more columns ("index", "indicator" and "level_0" with different values). think it would be easier to have just another column indicating from which dataframe the max_value is extracted (which the indicator column from your code is not doing, right?)

Comment: @palacinak That's what the `indicator` column does - it tells you whether max came from df_i, where `i` is 1, 2, 3, .... n. Please make sure you converted the series to dataframes.